# How can we return or proceed from before or after advice in aspectj?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

.
I am started to learn aspectj . While reading and practicing things ,I met with the case where i need to return the parameters which i extracted from method call in my before advice.But now i want to return(functionality of proceed())these parameters. I want to edit the the parameter `param` by and assign another string to it and send that parameter to it.So can anyone tell me how can i proceed from before or after advice..
here is my aspect code:

```
public aspect HelloAspect 
{
before(String param , HelloJava hello):call(void *.show(String))  && target(hello) && args(param)
    {

    }
}
```

In short i want alternative of proceed ()
Note that i have restriction on using around aspect.

Example will be appritiable  . .Thanks in advance . .

Comment: Why are you restricted from using `around` ?

Comment: @jbx this is my assignment given to do.and hint given is it can be done using target() .

Comment: So why don't you have a look at what target offers you?